# Publish an web application project to local directory from vs2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an web application project developed with vs2012 (fw 4.0). I want to publish it in my local folder. In later time, I 'll copy the published contents in server. How can i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this link:[Deploying ASP.NET Websites on IIS 7.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0). You need to have IIS 7 in order to publish your project.

Comment: @ChristianMark - I think s.k.paul just wants to get it into a local directory - and then manually copy the contents to some server. So he doesn't actually need to have IIS 7 (or any IIS) on his machine in this case. I've had to do similar in a case where we couldn't directly publish to the server, so we published to a local folder and then manually copied it over to the proper directory on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below step for publish web application

- Right click on web project and select "Publish" from menu.
- select Connection Tab
- Select publish method as "File system"
- Select Path in "Target Location"
- And finally click on "Publish" button

And after successfully publish check out target location